# NotificationListenerService : Stop Queue all current notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, accessibility, text-to-speech

I'm working on a notification based app, for which I need to listen to incoming notifications. I've been able to listen to incoming call,sms, mail etc. I have no clue how to listen for pings or messages from friends on Whatsapp via code. Can this actually be done but problem is that TTS service continue started.when user send message two time TTS service run two time. plz solve this problem...

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);


    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int state = telephonyManager.getCallState();

    if (state != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {

        String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();

        if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {

            if (packageName.contains("whatsapp")) {
                whatText = "Whatsapp Notification";
                initTTS(sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "");
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initTTS(String s) {
    text = whatText + " ";

    STD = s + " ";
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            stopSelf();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {

        }
    });
}
  @Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
         tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
         SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SET", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String Demo = preferences.getString("text", text);
        tts.speak(Demo + STD + " ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```